# Microwave cooking ready frozen meals

Tags: microwave

If a frozen ready meal states 9 minutes microwave cooking, how do I work out cooking time for two identical meals?

Comment: @PeteBecker if you have an answer, post an answer, please. Comments are not the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Do both fit in the microwave at the same time ?

Start at the recommended 9 minutes, test the temperature, nuke it for a few more minutes (2, 3 ) and test again.

If you have a rotary table inside, it will make thing easier, if not, move the 2 meals every couple of minutes.

Comment: It's often worth rotating each meal if they're next to each other, so that the inside edge becomes the outside, and vice versa.

Comment: I'd imagine a regular domestic mic would take them one atop the other, in which case one will get hit a lot harder than the other. I'd swap them top for bottom halfway through the first 9 mins too.

Answer (score -3):

I think 5 minutes for each will be enough. It also depends on the degree of freezing of the product.

Answer (score -3):

I turn on for 5 minutes at 100% power, and that's enough.